# How to change SpecificVersion to false for NuGet packages?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I would like to change `SpecificVersion` to `false` for internally used NuGet packages.
I am using `PackageReference` and not `packages.config`, if that makes a difference.

While searching a solution for this topic, I have found those results

GitHub Nuget: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1380

Which states

> In project.json (NuGet3) we are moving to a mode where NuGet does not touch the csproj file at all (where scenarios you are describing are partly the inspiration for the change).

I didn't manage to find the mentioned "project.json" file, where this could be possible? (Notice: the linked url is 7+ years old)

> What can you do
> You probably need to come up with a different way to define the
> settings in your csproj file. Instead of putting them on the reference
> that we know if going to change, we are going to use an msbuild
> feature that lets you apply the settings to a reference.
>
> You can go with the approach outlined by this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841913/modify-msbuild-itemgroup-metadata) post and use an
> msbuild target.

I did try to read the linked StackOverflow post but frankly speaking I don't understand how this can be used for my scenario.

Also I found this:

[Why is the NuGet Package Manager removing SpecificVersion False from the project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528069/why-is-the-nuget-package-manager-removing-specificversion-false-from-the-project)

Where it states

> You would probably have to write a PowerShell script to fix up the references that are changed on updating.

But I seem to fail to understand where a powershell script should write the necessary changes to make `SpecificVersion` `false`?

As I mentioned at the beginning, I am talking about internally used NuGet packages, so if there is a solution revolving around defining something in the `nuspec` or in the `csproj` file that gets packed into a NuGet package this would also be a approach I can take.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking.
Could you please provide a minimal csproj?
From what I can see `SpecificVersion` is for assembly references, not package references.

Comment: @svenhuebner - yes, but what I need is for all assemblies that are included in the package to be `SpecificVersion` = `false` - currently NuGet does automatically set it to `SpecificVersion` = `true` I would desperatly need to change this behaviour with whatever necessary steps

Answer (score 0):

Taking "whatever necessary steps" literally, you could explicitly reference the assemblies within the package instead of relying on `PackageReference` default behavior. This ties your csproj to the folder structure of the package, though.
It will also probably break anything the package does to the consumer's csproj with its own .props and .targets files.

I did not test this:

```
<!-- Define assets so that the package is basically ignored,
     because we want to manually reference its assemblies. -->
<PackageReference Include="MyPackage.SomeWhere" PrivateAssets="all" IncludeAssets="none" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
<!-- Reference assemblies manually with the path property from above as base folder
     Repeat for all assemblies in the package -->
<Reference Include="$(PkgMyPackage_SomeWhere)/lib/net461/SomeAssembly.dll" SpecificVersion="false" />
```